# What does an asterisk preceding a PushedFilters entail in a Spark SQL Explain Plan

Tags: sql, apache-spark, filter

Regarding Spark PushedFilters showing in Spark Physical Explain Plans it's stated that (ref.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkPredicatePushdown.html):

> The asterisk indicates that push down filter will be handled only at the datasource level.

What does this mean and more importantly when you see a PushedFilters array entry without an asterisk,
is the filter still being pushed down to the data source level or not and handled out side of it, but
why call it a Pushed Filter then in the first place?

Very confusing and googling it I couldn't find a real answer to the question.

Thanks!

Jan

Answer (score 1):

Pushdown of predicates always happen at the data source level. It happens in a manner that the datasource would selectively scan those pieces of data which are predicated upon. Spark is just a processing engine which hands over the query to the datasource for final execution. The data source on the other hand would execute the query as it wishes. The Spark-sql connectors are aware of the behavior of datasources (based on the schema) so they can predict a physical plan with pushdown predicates but they can't guarantee that it will run, so the asterisk.

I ran a query against a local parquet file. The physical plan has pushed down predicate and no asterisk. It is a local parquet file which Spark reads itself so the physical plan is 100% accurate.

```
    val df = spark.read.parquet("/Users/Documents/temp/temp1")
    df.filter($"income" >= 30).explain(true)


== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [client#0, type#1, address#2, type_2#3, income#4]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(income#4) && (income#4 >= 30))
   +- *(1) FileScan parquet [client#0,type#1,address#2,type_2#3,income#4] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/User/Documents/temp/temp1], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(income), GreaterThanOrEqual(income,30)], ReadSchema: struct<client:string,type:string,address:string,type_2:string,income:int>
```

Here a table is read from Oracle using Spark-SQL. The Oracle DB uses predicate push down and index access but Spark has no idea about it.

```
== Physical Plan ==
Execute InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand file:/data/.., false, Parquet, Map(codec -> org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappyCodec, path -> /data/...), Overwrite, [COLUMN_01, COLUMN_02, COLUMN_03, COLUMN_04, COLUMN_05, COLUMN_06, COLUMN_07, COLUMN_08, COLUMN_09, COLUMN_10, COLUMN_11, COLUMN_12, COLUMN_13, COLUMN_14, COLUMN_15, COLUMN_16, COLUMN_17, COLUMN_18, ... 255 more fields]
+- Project [COLUMN_01#1246, COLUMN_02#1247, COLUMN_03#1248, COLUMN_04#1249, COLUMN_05#1250, COLUMN_06#1251, COLUMN_07#1252, COLUMN_08#1253, COLUMN_09#1254, COLUMN_10#1255, COLUMN_11#1256, COLUMN_12#1257, COLUMN_13#1258, COLUMN_14#1259, COLUMN_15#1260, COLUMN_16#1261, COLUMN_17#1262, COLUMN_18#1263, ... 255 more fields]
   +- Scan JDBCRelation((select cu.*, ROWIDTONCHAR(t.rowid) as ROW_ID from table t  where (column1 in (786567473,786567520,786567670,786567570,...........)) and column2 in (10,11, ...) and t.result is null)t) [numPartitions=20] [COLUMN_87#1332,COLUMN_182#1427,COLUMN_128#1373,COLUMN_104#1349,COLUMN_189#1434,COLUMN_108#1353,COLUMN_116#1361,COLUMN_154#1399,COLUMN_125#1370,COLUMN_120#1365,COLUMN_267#1512,COLUMN_54#1299,COLUMN_100#1345,COLUMN_230#1475,COLUMN_68#1313,COLUMN_44#1289,COLUMN_53#1298,COLUMN_97#1342,COLUMN_03#1248,COLUMN_16#1261,COLUMN_43#1288,COLUMN_50#1295,COLUMN_174#1419,COLUMN_20#1265,... 254 more fields] PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<COLUMN_87:string,COLUMN_182:string,COLUMN_128:string,COLUMN_104:string,COLUMN_189:string,C...
```

Comment: Thanks Salim for your response! The push down filter without asterisk, what does that 
 mean? I read in this thread https://gitter.im/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector?at=5cd55cde8fcdb05d47afc3c0  that push down filters without asterisk execute slower and i was wondering whether that is the difference between with and without asterisk.

Comment: Imagine 2 datasources - a local parquet file vs a remove table on a database. Spark will read the file itself as compared to Spark will depend on the database to read data. The plan for reading a local parquet file doesn't have asterisk vs the one reading from remote database does.

Comment: Hi Salim,

The 2nd Physical plan I think has an empty push down filter array, PushedFilters: [], 
because it's an insert which has no where clause.

I noticed in our Physical explain plan that isnotnull() filters go without a * which don't have any peer in the SQL query where clause but inserted by Spark itself and actual where clauses we have in the SQL query get a *. An example:

                PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(TYPE), *EqualTo(TYPE,BAR)]

I still have no idea how these two filters get executed / pushed down (sorry! ::)

Comment: @JB007 that is my point that Spark has no idea of execution when the data source reads the data for Spark - example being Oracle DB. When Spark read a local parquet file it can tell exactly how data will be read. For special data connectors like the one for Cassandra, Spark will have better idea about execution but again can't guarantee the execution so puts a *.